# actualizar dato actual, con información del dato anterior

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito hacer un UPDATE de la linea actual,
pero para esto necesito trabajar con un dato anterior.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito actualizar los campos seleccionados en azul,
como ven el `h_codigo_padre` es el mismo y tiene siempre un `'SALDO_INICIAL'` en este caso comienza con `'110000'`.

Para actualizar el siguiente campo de abajo en columna `'z_cant_fisica_total'`,

debo sumar el `'z_cant_fisica_total'` del registro anterior con el `'tcan_fisica'` del registro actual.

todo esto lo debo hacer con PHP 5.1 .

estaba intentando de obtener el `'z_cant_fisica_final'` del registro anterior restándole al `'id'` actual `-1` , pero no me sirve para el segundo registro, ya que siempre le `id` del primer registro no es correlativo.

adjunto while en php:

```
while ($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($result_sql4)) {
    $id = $row4['id'];
    $h_codigo_padre = $row4['h_codigo_padre'];
    $p_tipo = $row4['p_tipo'];
    $cant_entrada = $row4['t_cant_fisica'];
    $cant_salida  = $row4['w_cant_fisica'];
    $cant_inicial = $row4['z_cant_fisica_final'];

    //intento rescatar el saldo final anterior restando -1 al id, pero no sirve para el primer registro porque no viene en correlativo
    $id_penultimo = $id - 1 ;
    $sql5 = "SELECT z_cant_fisica_final FROM PE_import_det_mensual_kardex WHERE id='".$id_penultimo."'";
    $result_sql5 = mysql_query($sql5,$db);
    $total_anterior = $row5['z_cant_fisica_final'];

    // sumamos el saldo final anterior, con la entrada de la linea actual.
    $s_final    =  (float) $total_anterior + (float) $cant_entrada ;

    //actualizamos el saldo final  de la linea actual
    $sql6 = "UPDATE  PE_import_det_mensual_kardex SET z_cant_fisica_final='".$s_final."' WHERE id='".$id."'";
    $result_sql6 = mysql_query($sql6,$db);

}
```

estaba revisando :

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY id
    ) AS row_num
FROM ......
```

pero no es compatible con mi MYSQL.

Comment: No es buena idea guardar existencia en cada movimiento del kárdex, porque si debes insertar, eliminar o modificar una entrada necesitarías recorrer todos los movimientos para actualizarlos. Lo ideal es tener una tabla aparte donde se guarden existencia inicial, total de entradas, total de salidas y existencia final por periodo (mes). Cada que generes listado de movimientos realizas los cálculos para mostrar ese dato. Aparte, parece que no tienes una columna para guardar fecha del movimiento.

Comment: @Triby si tengo, solo que aca la muestro simplificada. mi solucion de momento es agregar un indice en el por el back, y filtrar el query por el codigo.

Comment: Por lo que estas diciendo, si queres hacerlo en php es tan simple como traer la tabla ordenada por fecha e ir sumando a mano y actualizando.. o vos queres hacerlo en sql?

Comment: tienen la misma fecha algunos, por ende nome sirve rescatar el dato anterior por la fecha.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes probar los siguiente:

```
$query="UPDATE Nombre_table set z_cant_fisica_total=(SALDO_INICIAL+tcan_fisica) WHERE ID=$id";
```

MYSQL reconoce el valor actual del registro y podes hacer lo que quieras con el

Comment: se debe jugar con el dato `z_cant_fisica_final` del registro anterior, no con el actual.

Comment: Amigo esa es la respuesta, no me des -1 porque esa es la respuesta

Comment: estimado, tu respuesta esta actualizando el dato con la informacion de la linea actual. pon un poco mas de atencion en la consulta.